# how to define start value for GORM auto increment

Tags: mysql, go, auto-increment, go-gorm

I'm using gorm in my project, and I need to set a started value for its auto-increment function.
I tried adding this line, but no progress:

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID         uint `gorm:"primarykey;autoIncrement:100"`
    Email      string `gorm:"not null; unique" form:"email" binding:"required"`
}
```

How can I define a starter value like 100 for the gorm AutoIncrement function?

Comment: What database are you using? How is the database structure created (migration tool, etc.)?

Comment: I'm using MySQL and the tables are created by AutoMigrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, you can do it natively with gorm. It's a bit hacky, but you could execute a raw SQL query after your AutoMigrate to set the increment value:

```sql
SELECT GREATEST(100, MAX(id) + 1) FROM table_name INTO @autoinc;
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = @autoinc;
```

This way you make sure, the value is minimum 100 (if there are no rows in the table), or it is the next value if there are rows already.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. after your automigrate code , you can write this code:

```
DB.Create(
 <your_table_model>{
    ID: <start_value>, 
    DeletedAt: gorm.DeletedAt{Time: time.Now(), Valid: true}}
)
```